# Technique for solving $ x^4 - x^3 + x - 1 = 0 $

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Here's another idiotic algebra question that I can't seem to make any progress on.

$$  x^4 - x^3 + x - 1 = 0 $$

I tried to make it into a quadratic: Let $ u = x^2 $, then

$$ u^2 - xu + x - 1 = 0 $$

However, attempting to apply the quadratic formula to this just resulted in a gigantic circular mess from which I could not escape. I think there is probably a way to factor the original equation but as usual I can't seem to magically summon the factors from thin air.

Comment: A start: $x^3(x-1)+(x-1)$.

Comment: Try factoring $x^3$ from the first two terms, and then factoring by grouping.

Comment: If nothing is obvious, the first thing to try is  the [rational root theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem) to see if there are any rational roots. In this case the theorem says that if there is a rational root, it will be $\pm 1$.  Checking these reveals that $+1$ is a root, so you know immediately that the polynomial factors into a product of $x-1$ and some cubic. Next you should find out what this cubic is; maybe it will seem more tractable than the original quartic.

Comment: The $u=x^2$ trick only works if the original polynomial has the form $ax^4 + bx^2 + c = 0$. If there is an $x^3$ or an $x$ term, as in this case, there is no way to   replace those terms with simple functions of of $u$, so you get a gigantic circular mess, as you observed.

Comment: @MJD yeah, that's what I realized; my b term was not cooperating.

Comment: @AndréNicolas thanks - that's the clue I needed; I can factor it from there.

Comment: @TonyK - not sure what you mean about 1 - 1 + 1 - 1.

Comment: @MJD thanks also for the link to the Rational Root Theorem. I didn't know about that trick.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @André Nicolas suggests, the best approach is to factor by grouping.

Factoring out $x^3$ from the terms in expression $x^4-x^3$ makes the left hand side of your equation become:

$$
x^3(x-1)+(x-1)
$$

From there, you can factor an $(x-1)$ from both terms, finally resulting in:
$$
(x-1)(x^3+1)
$$
Notice that $x^3+1 = x^3+1^3$, you can use a "sum of cubes" formula to further factorize the right part of that expression. You should obtain:

$$
(x-1)(x+1)(x^2-x+1)
$$

Setting this product of factors equal to zero should be the easiest part, as you can use the quadratic formula for the rightmost factor.